# Strange GHCi lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, ghci

I define two mutually recursive lists for even and odd numbers in ghci as follows:

```
> let evens = 0:map (+1) odds; odds = map (+1) evens
```

And then I consult the thunks using `:sp`

```
> :sp evens
evens = _
> :sp odds
odds = _
> take 5 evens
[0,2,4,6,8]
> :sp evens
evens = 0 : 2 : 4 : 6 : 8 : _
:sp odds
odds = _
```

Notice how the `odds` thunk is not evaluated although `evens` has been evaluated to the 5th element. I can think of an intuitive explanation for this. `odds` has to be explicitly invoked to be evaluated:

```
> take 5 odds
[1,3,5,7,9]
>:sp odds
odds = 1 : 3 : 5 : 7 : 9 : _
```

However, now when I do this:

```
> take 10 evens
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
> :sp evens
evens = 0 : 2 : 4 : 6 : 8 : 10 : 12 : 14 : 16 : 18 : _
> :sp odds
odds = 1 : 3 : 5 : 7 : 9 : 11 : 13 : 15 : 17 : _
```

Notice how the `odds` thunk is now evaluated whenever `evens` is evaluated? Why was `odds` not evaluated the first time and evaluated the second time and in all subsequent evaluations? What's happening?

Comment: couldn't reproduce that. what's your OS, ghc version etc?

Comment: I can reproduce it on Win7 with GHC 7.6.3.  I can also do `take 5 odds` and get the same behavior for `:sp evens`, which really doesn't make sense because `evens` has the literal `0` in it.

Comment: I have a guess: `evens` and `odds` are "sort of" polymorphic until you observe them explicitly the first time. Then they're magically monomorphed into `[Integer]` and from then on everything is visible. e.g. try adding `evens, odds :: [Integer]` to your `let` to see the difference.

Comment: @bheklilr When a literal "looks like a function" it doesn't get early evaluated. Compare `let x = [1,2,3,4]` and `let y () = [1,2,3,4]`. If we do `:sp x` we get `x = [1,2,3,4]` but `:sp y ()` is `y = _`. So in this case the literal `0` in `evens` won't get early evaluated since it's not obviously a constant.

Comment: @DanielWagner The default type signature for `evens` and `odds` is `[Integer]`, at least till ghc 7.6.3. This is the type inferred without having to explicitly mention it. Why should mentioning the type make any difference? I think this just means that there is a bug in either the type infrencer or `:sp` itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has to do with how mutually recursive bindings are compiled by GHC (and there's a difference whether the bindings have an explicit type signature or not).

Let's write the following simple program which exposes the same problem but removes all suspicion on the role that integer overloading or the monomorphism restriction could play:

```
module MutRec where

ft = False : map not tf
tf = map not ft
```

Loading this into GHCi (I'm using 7.6.3) yields:

```
*MutRec> take 5 ft
[False,False,False,False,False]
*MutRec> :sp ft
ft = False : False : False : False : False : _
*MutRec> :sp tf
tf = _
```

Let's look at the Core code for this module

```
$ ghc -O0 MutRec -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all
[1 of 1] Compiling MutRec           ( MutRec.hs, MutRec.o )

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 28, types: 42, coercions: 0}

Rec {
ft1_rkA
ft1_rkA = : False a_rkC

tf1_rkB
tf1_rkB = map not ft1_rkA

a_rkC
a_rkC = map not tf1_rkB
end Rec }

ds_rkD
ds_rkD = (ft1_rkA, tf1_rkB)

ft
ft = case ds_rkD of _ { (ft2_Xkp, tf2_Xkr) -> ft2_Xkp }

tf
tf = case ds_rkD of _ { (ft2_Xkq, tf2_Xks) -> tf2_Xks }
```

This explains it all. The mutually recursive definitions end up in a `Rec` block, referring each other directly. But then GHC is building a pair `ds_rkD` and re-extracts the components from the pair. This is an extra indirection. It explains why after partially evaluating `ft` in GHCi, the top of `tf` will still appear as a thunk, even if underneath there has been evaluation. In fact, we can verify that just doing minimal evaluation on `tf` is enough to expose this:

```
*MutRec> take 5 ft
[False,False,False,False,False]
*MutRec> :sp ft
ft = False : False : False : False : False : _
*MutRec> :sp tf
tf = _
Prelude MutRec> seq tf ()
()
Prelude MutRec> :sp tf
tf = True : True : True : True : _
```

If we add explicit type sigantures to `ft` and `tf` or enable optimization, the tuple construction does not happen:

```
$ ghc -O MutRec -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all
[1 of 1] Compiling MutRec           ( MutRec.hs, MutRec.o )

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 12, types: 11, coercions: 0}

Rec {
ft1
ft1 = map not tf

ft
ft = : False ft1

tf
tf = map not ft
end Rec }
```

Now GHCi will behave more naturally.

---

#### Edit

I've looked at the GHC sources to try to figure out the reason for the difference in
behaviour. It seems it's a side effect of how type inference works for polymorphic bindings.

If a binding is polymorphic but doesn't have a type signature, then it's recursive uses are
monomorphic. This is a restriction in Hindley-Milner that GHC also implements. If you want
polymorphic recursion, you need an additional type signature.

To model this faithfully in the Core language, the desugarer makes a monomorphic copy of
every unannotated recursive function. This monomorphic version is used in the recursive
calls, the generalized version is used for external calls. You can see this even for a small
function such as `rep` (which is a reimplementation of `repeat`). The desugared core for

```
rep x = x : rep x
```

is

```
rep
rep =
  \ (@ a_aeM) ->
    letrec {
      rep_aeJ
      rep_aeJ =
        \ (x_aeH :: a_aeM) -> : @ a_aeM x_aeH (rep_aeJ x_aeH); } in
    rep_aeJ
```

The outer `rep` is polymorphic, hence the type abstraction `\ (@ a_aeM) ->` in the beginning. The inner `rep_aeJ` is monomorphic and used in the recursive call.

If you add an explicit type annotation to `rep`

```
rep :: a -> [a]
rep x = x : rep x
```

then the recursive calls are to the polymorphic version, and the generated Core becomes
simpler:

```
Rec {
rep
rep = \ (@ a_b) (x_aeH :: a_b) -> : @ a_b x_aeH (rep @ a_b x_aeH)
end Rec }
```

You can see how the type argument `@ a_b` is picked up in the beginning and reapplied
to `rep` in every recursive call.

The tuple construction we're seeing for mutually recursive bindings is simply a
generalization of this principle. You build up inner monomorphic versions of the mutually
recursive functions, then generalize them in a tuple, and extract the polymorphic
versions from the tuple.

All this happens independently of whether the bindings are actually polymorphic or not.
It's sufficient for them to be recursive. I think this behaviour of GHC is completely
correct and ok, in particular because optimisation takes care of the performance hit.

Comment: But the fact that the behavior changes after adding an explicit type signature is unjustified, isn't it?

Comment: @is7s *Does* the behavior change? The result doesn't. GHC is "allowed" to use any evaluation strategy it likes that doesn't change the result. `:sp` is peeking into implementation details that aren't normally "exposed". I too would be interested in a note on what the tuple construction achieves for GHC, though.

Comment: @Ben But it is an extra level of indirection, thus a performance hit. I would never think that adding the type which was already inferred correctly could make any difference in terms of performance!

Comment: @is7s I've edited my answer. I agree with Ben that GHC is allowed to do what it does. It doesn't make sens to complain about a potential performance hit in an unoptimized Haskell program. It would only be a problem if optimizations wouldn't take care of it.

Comment: `If a binding is polymorphic but doesn't have a type signature` ... but in our case the binding is actually monomorphic. The inferred type is `[Integer]`.

Comment: @is7s Quoting from my own answer: "All this happens independently of whether the bindings are actually polymorphic or not. It's sufficient for them to be recursive." I guess this could be changed, but perhaps it doesn't seem worth the special case.